# How can I test user authentication separately?

Tags: react-native, detox

I just want to write e2e test for react native app which is already developed with react-native. I can separate test cases but I can't run test cases with app-flow order.

For example, I want to test settings part of my app. But user should be logged in. And I want to run authentication.test.js and after that settings.test.js.

Are there any way to do that?